# comparing strings with -0 fail

Tags: php, if-statement, zero

I cannot manage to do a succesful comparison with the string "-0"

```
if(strval("-0") == strval("0")) {
    echo '"-0" seems to be same "0"';
}
```

Result:

> "-0" seems to be same "0"

What am I missing here?

And more important, how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "===" operator

```
if(strval("-0") === strval("0")) {
    echo '"-0" seems to be same "0"';
}
```

but why are you using strval() if the values are strings already?

Comment: Thank you. I used the strval to avoid disussions about type of variable.